# How to use sdl2 with CoDeBlocks

Tags: codeblocks, sdl-2

I have a very hard time to set up SDL2 with Code::Blocks
I tried some tutorials found on Google and also I tried to solve the issues by searching on this site but I failed to solve it,  everytime I got errors while compiling a simple program
so I wish someone is kind enough to give me an easy step by step guide to help me
first of all let me know if code::blocks and sdl 2 work wlel together?

then I have to say, I'm using a HP portable with Windows 7 - 64 BITS 
I got Code::Blocks 12.11 with the embbeded Mingw32 4.7.1 installed on it 
I think I linked the libs and include files properly on my settings but still never got something working , I'm about to give up

Comment: Can you update your question with errors you get?

Answer (score 2):

1. download SDL2-devel-2.0.1-mingw.tar.gz
2. unpack from SDL2-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32 these dirs: \bin, \include, \lib and \share to e.g. X:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\
3. Create directory %APPDATA%\CodeBlocks\UserTemplates\SDL2 and paste files SDL2.cbp, main.cpp, and cb.bmp

SDL2.cbp:

Note: Edit the letter of your drive and path X:\CodeBlocks as you need

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<CodeBlocks_project_file>
        <FileVersion major="1" minor="6" />
        <Project>
                <Option title="SDL2" />
                <Option pch_mode="2" />
                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                <Build>
                        <Target title="Debug">
                                <Option output="bin/Debug/SDL2" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                                <Option object_output="obj/Debug/" />
                                <Option type="1" />
                                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                                <Compiler>
                                        <Add option="-g" />
                                </Compiler>
                        </Target>
                        <Target title="Release">
                                <Option output="bin/Release/SDL2" prefix_auto="1" extension_auto="1" />
                                <Option object_output="obj/Release/" />
                                <Option type="0" />
                                <Option compiler="gcc" />
                                <Compiler>
                                        <Add option="-O2" />
                                </Compiler>
                                <Linker>
                                        <Add option="-s" />
                                </Linker>
                        </Target>
                </Build>
                <Compiler>
                        <Add option="-Wall" />
                        <Add directory="X:/CodeBlocks/MinGW/include" />
                </Compiler>
                <Linker>
                        <Add library="mingw32" />
                        <Add library="SDL2main" />
                        <Add library="SDL2.dll" />
                        <Add library="user32" />
                        <Add library="gdi32" />
                        <Add library="winmm" />
                        <Add library="dxguid" />
                        <Add directory="X:/CodeBlocks/MinGW/lib" />
                </Linker>
                <Unit filename="cb.bmp" />
                <Unit filename="main.cpp" />
                <Extensions>
                        <code_completion />
                        <envvars />
                        <debugger />
                        <lib_finder disable_auto="1" />
                </Extensions>
        </Project>
</CodeBlocks_project_file>
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main ( int argc, char** argv )
{
// initialize SDL video
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to init SDL video: "<< SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
// make sure SDL cleans up before exit
    atexit(SDL_Quit);

// create a new window
    SDL_Window* screen = NULL;
    screen = SDL_CreateWindow("CodeBlocs Logo Window",
                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                          SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                          150,120,
                          /* SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN | */
                          SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL);
    if ( NULL == screen )
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create window: "<< SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

// Create a new renderer
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = NULL;
    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(screen, -1, 0);

    if ( NULL == renderer )
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to create renderer: "<< SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

// load an image
    SDL_Surface* bitmap = NULL;
    bitmap = SDL_LoadBMP("cb.bmp");

    if ( NULL == bitmap )
    {
        std::cout << "Unable to load bitmap: "<< SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    SDL_Texture* texture = NULL;
    texture = SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, bitmap);
    SDL_FreeSurface(bitmap);

    // program main loop
    bool done = false;
    while (!done)
    {
    // drawing
    SDL_RenderClear(renderer);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        // message processing loop
        SDL_Event event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&event))
        {
            // check for messages
            switch (event.type)
            {
            // exit if the window is closed
            case SDL_QUIT:
                done = true;
                break;

            // check for keypresses
            case SDL_KEYDOWN:
                {
                    // exit if ESCAPE is pressed
                    if (event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE)
                        done = true;
                    break;
                }
            } // end switch
        } // end of message processing
    } // end main loop

    SDL_DestroyTexture(texture);
    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(screen);

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

cb.bmp any bitmap file 150x120

Run CodeBlocks and File->New->From templates...->User Templates->SDL2